# How to fix Platform Exception error "auth_in_progress" for flutter local authentication?

Tags: dart, flutter, fingerprint

I'm trying to implement fingerpritn authentication in my flutter app using local_auth plugin. But it is throwing me Platform Exception Error:

"PlatformException(auth_in_progress, Authentication in progress, null)"

```
final LocalAuthentication _localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
bool authenticated = false;
try {
  authenticated = await _localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
    localizedReason: 'Scan your fingerprint to authenticate',
    useErrorDialogs: true,
    stickyAuth: false
  );
} on PlatformException
catch(e) {
  print(e);
}
return authenticated; }
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

This happens on Android. You have to modify your MainActivity to implement FlutterFragmentActivity to use local_auth plugin. Change your code from this (Kotlin on my example):

```
import android.os.Bundle

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

To this:

```
import android.os.Bundle

import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

Also you need to add this two lines to your gradle.properties file.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

This error is hard to find since version 0.5.1, because the plugin doesn't throw the right exception, and the documentation doesn't tell you to implement this base class.

Comment: I am using local_auth: ^0.6.1+3. I am facing issue with GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this) line. registerWith is expecting flutterEngine object and I am giving MainActivity context.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. Local auth works for the first time, but after you minimize an app and then mazimize, the auth activity appears but the app crashes when you touch a scanner

Comment: @Konstantin any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a simple solution. Before calling the LocalAuthentication().authenticate()

We can call await LocalAuthentication().stopAuthentication();

That helped me to fix the code

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue:

- Changing `android/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt`

```
    package ....
   
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
    import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
    
    class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
        override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        }
    }
```

- Is Disable, enable SplashScreenDrawable in AndroidManifest `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

or Java Version

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by removing `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` properties from my `gradle.properties` file.

This is all I have in my `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by set the `stickyAuth` option as `true` in `authenticate` method.

```dart
auth.authenticate(
              stickyAuth: true,
              ...
          )
```

See the [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/local_auth/latest/local_auth/LocalAuthentication/authenticate.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I think its too late to response but as it said in [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) docs :

you should use `Sticky Auth` and set it as true

it worked for me btw

```
 await _localAuthentication.authenticate(
          localizedReason: 'Please authenticate to show account balance',
          stickyAuth: true,
          biometricOnly: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. But none of the above answers useful. Tricky solution is to set "sensitiveTransaction" value to false. By default this value is true.

When user clicks on biometric button, by default it will come two dialogs. One is faceid or fingerprint recognition and 2nd one is for confirmation dialog. At this case, if user clicks on cancel, permission denied and it will never asks again. If "sensitiveTransaction" sets  to false will not ask for confirm after verified with faceid or fingerprint.

```
await localAuthObject.authenticate(
              localizedReason:
                  'Scan your fingerprint (or face or whatever) to authenticate',
              useErrorDialogs: false,
              sensitiveTransaction: false,
              stickyAuth: true,
              biometricOnly:
                  false);
```